# Set a custom % of 1's into a 2D blank array, where the 1's are randomly shuffled?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, shuffle, 2d-games

I've been a long time lurker on Stack Overflow but I couldn't seem to find a suitable existing solution...

I'm learning JS and HTML, and I've been playing around with 2D arrays to make game board. So far I made a custom # of rows/columns for a game board with all white tiles (represented as 0 for now).

My goal is to use an input field for a % of black tiles (represented as 1) to fill up the board (2D Array), but the black tiles have to be randomly distributed/shuffled among it.

Here's what I've got so far..

https://jsfiddle.net/5pvm4mmy/6/

```
function generateArray() {

var myNode = document.getElementById("table");
while (myNode.firstChild) {
    myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
}

rows = $("#rows-field").val();
cols = $("#cols-field").val();

concentration = $("#concentration-field").val()
source = $("#source-field").val();
target = $("#target-field").val();



var table = document.getElementById("table");
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        if (i%2 == j%2) {
            td.className = "white";
        } else {
            td.className = "black";
        }
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
}
document.body.appendChild(table);


}
```

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear - where exactly is your problem? From how I understood all you need is to use the `Math.random()` function and check if the value is above some predetermined other value to see whether you write 0 or 1 to your array. (Also your code does not have any actual references to 0 or 1 instead using "black" and "white" which makes the question more confusing).

Comment: Never mind. Your Math.random() advice solved my problem. Sorry about the unclear question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a random selection of a predefined set of values, you can use a stack. Think of it as a deck of cards and you pick a random card each time from the number of card left in the deck. In this case you have only 2 values but you may want to set the number of black and white. For this you can use a pseudo stack.

```
var black = 29;  // 29 blacks the rest white
var white = (rows * cols) - black;

function getRandSquare(){
    var select = Math.floor(Math.random() * (black + white));
    if(select > black){
        white -= 1;
        return "white";
    }
    black -= 1;
    return "black";
}
```

If you have many options like a deck of cards you use an array.

Example of a random stack.

```
// create a deck
var cards = [];
for(var c = 0; c < 52; c++){
    cards[c] = c;
}
function shuffle(cards){
    var shuf = []; // to hold the shuffled deck
    while(cards.length > 0){ // pick a random item, take it from the stack and
                             // put on the new stack until there are no items
                             // left
        shuf.push(cards.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length),1));
    }
    return shuf;  // return shuffled deck
}

cards = shuffle(cards); // get shuffled deck.
```

Which will work for anything where you need to pick randomly from a predefined set. It only takes one pass and the set is as random as the random number generator

To show psuedo stack working ... Always has 60 black

```js
var cont;
function draw(){
    var rows = 15;
    var cols = 15;
    var black = 60;  // 29 blacks the rest white
    var white = (rows * cols) - black;
    
    function getRandSquare(){
        var select = Math.floor(Math.random() * (black + white));
        if(select > black-1){
            white -= 1;
            return "white";
        }
        black -= 1;
        return "black";
    }
 
    var bCount = 0;
    cont = document.createElement("div");
    for(var y = 0; y < rows; y++){
        for(var x = 0; x < cols; x++){
            var s = document.createElement("span");
            s.className = getRandSquare();
            if(s.className === "black"){
               s.textContent = bCount;
               bCount += 1;
            }
            s.style.top = ((y+2) * 20) + "px";
            s.style.left = (x * 20) + "px";
            s.style.width = "20px";
            s.style.height = "20px";
            cont.appendChild(s);                                         
        }
      
    }
    document.body.appendChild(cont);
}
document.body.onclick = function(){
  document.body.removeChild(cont);
  cont = null;
  draw();
}
draw();
```

```css
span {
  position:absolute;
  border : 1px solid;
  font-size : small;
  text-align : center;
}
.black {
  background : black;
  border-color :white;
  color : white;
}
.white {
  background : white;
  border-color :black;
}
```

```html
<h3>Click to randomise</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I got it done, thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/5pvm4mmy/8/

```
function generateArray() {

var myNode = document.getElementById("table");
while (myNode.firstChild) {
    myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
}

rows = $("#rows-field").val();
cols = $("#cols-field").val();

concentration = $("#concentration-field").val();
source = $("#source-field").val();
target = $("#target-field").val();



var table = document.getElementById("table");
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        if (concentration < Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)) {
            td.className = "white";
        } else {
            td.className = "black";
        }
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
}
document.body.appendChild(table);


}
```